# How to make Jasper report visible to User "A" only Not "B" which is created by User "A" as jasper user

Tags: roles, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReports Server 6.2.x* to create reports and Dashboards. I am a Jasper user "A"  having ROLE_USER ACCESS. I have created new report(in user level only) named "Y" based on my existing report "X" with Input given. The "Y" report should be visible to only the User "A"  not the other jasper users. i.e. The Report which i have created and saved newly based on existing reports should be visible only to me.

How to achieve this in *JR Server 6.2*?

Comment: Depends... do you have superuser / jasperadmin rights to add new users or roles?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have superuser / jasperadmin rights to add new users or roles. It is not about adding user or role. 
User will be created automatically in jasper server when i m navigating from my java application. 
All the user will be having ROLE_USER access by default and they can view all the reports available under the particular tenant.
Now User can create their new report by filtering records.

Comment: Cont.. (Say for eg. Report name is "EMPLOYEE DETAILS Report". Now One user have created report called "QA EMPLOYEE DETAILS Report By Nagarajan" and its Filtered based on Employee Designation(QA). Now i am saving this filtered records as new report with name "QA EMPLOYEE DETAILS Report By Nagarajan").

Comment: Cont.. In this case, When I am navigating from java application to jasper server again, I only should able to view this report "EMPLOYEE DETAILS Report By Nagarajan". 
It should not be visible to others. Because I have created this report for my use.
Basically I want to achieve something like private public report concept in jasper.

Comment: Is this the community or professional version of the server?

Comment: I am using Community Server version 6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

For every group you need additionally add another `ROLE`, e.g. `ROLE_Nagarajan`. Then add the role to your (and only your) user.

NOTE: *Do not remove the standard role `ROLE_USER` on the user which gets the new role. It is needed for the server to work properly.*

On the newly created report, deny any access from `ROLE_USER` and allow access from `ROLE_Nagarajan`.

Now only the user assigned to this role can see and access the newly created report.

If working with folders, you can assign those rights to a folder. Then everything stored in the folder will be only accessible by you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in your case, I have to create new role for each user. Say for eg. If 1000 users are logging into the jasper server to access reports, Every one will create their report as I said earlier. So, I will have READ_ONLY for all by default. Apart from this, I should have ROLE_USER1 for User1, ROLE_USER2 for User2 and so on.. But, This is not possible for me.

Comment: Oh I understood that you wanted to have this behaviour only for yourself. Indeed, the only other way is the way you described - a maintenance nightmare. In the pro version it is possible to separate at least between departments, but here you would have to make some folder trickery (which I would do) and understand the concept, that new reports are by default available for all users (in the folder / role).